# UV map onto existing image

Tags: uv

I'm new to Blender and I have to figure out how to do this one thing for a project that I am working on.

I have an object, which I have unwrapped. I have an existing png with a size of 220x100 pixels, and it contains certain textures at specific pixels that I want to fit onto my texture. Is there any way I can generate a UV map with this same ratio (instead of 1:1 as it is now) and also position each of the faces at a specific pixel value so that it lines up with the existing UV map image? I have attached the point that I am at so far below.

[image]

Comment: Load the image into the UV image editor first, then unwrap. The UV space will be shaped with the proportions of the image.

Comment: A different way to go about it: load the image into the image UV/image editor, place the 3d view so that is perpendicular with the object. Then use Project from view Bounds. That way the selected faces will use the entirety of the image for the UV map.

Comment: @cegaton Thanks! I was able to use your first suggestion. Do you know of any way I can set a specific pixel size and/or pixel location of each face of my object so that I can match my texture exactly, instead of just dragging and eyeballing each face?

Comment: Nevermind I got it, I was able to finish! Thanks again

Comment: please write an answer to your own question in the answers section. Other users who have a similar question could learn from your experience.